# Why can't I assign the return of a LINQ Find() or FirstOrDefault() result?

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var people = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name = "foo" },
            new Person { Name = "bar" }
        };

        // ERROR: Left-hand side must be a variable, property, or indexer
        people.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "foo") = new Person();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Why is the above `FirstOrDefault` line not valid .NET code? If the return of `FirstOrDefault()` isn't a variable, what is it?

Edit: I understand how to make this valid .NET code - my point is trying to get a concrete answer as to why this is not valid. A definition from the docs perhaps as to why. I don't need to see how to make it correct :)

Comment: your not storing it in a variable

Comment: _Person p = people.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "foo")_

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It will *always* return a value in memory.  It may have populated that in-memory value off of data in a database, but there *is* some in-memory object that it is returning.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That is true, it is a value, not a variable, but it possibly coming from a database wouldn't be the reason it doesn't (or couldn't) map to a variable.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough, I wasn't trying to point out the value vs variable rules in the spec, I was trying to point out that assigning an object to the output of a linq statement doesn't make sense in the general sense. Point not very well made apparently ;)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson If methods could actually return variables then it wouldn't be out of the question to have LINQ-like methods that returned values.  There would unquestionably need to be *versions* that didn't, but also having versions that returned variables would be quite useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot assign to the return of a function you need to store it in a variable

```
var person = people.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "foo") ?? new Person();
```

FirstOrDefault is a Get method it is not an array indexer you cannot use it to set values, For instance what do you expect your original statement accomplish

```
 people.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "foo") = new Person();
```

you cannot use it for anything afterwards until it is in a variable.

A method returns used for returning values if you want to set in the method you must use an out parameter or reference, or a property.

Comment: I think the ignorant understanding is that the 2nd code snippet you wrote would simply assign the reference found by the predicate to a new (empty) `Person`. If you can explain why that isn't implemented by .NET in that way (by definition?), then that'd be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: That is by design of a language, a method should be used for returning a value, a property, or member can be used for assignment.  Thats like asking why people don't get into a car through a trunk? It may be possible for a compiler to do, but it's by design

Comment: @johnny5 Having methods return variables is actually something that plenty of other languages do, and even something that was considered for adding to C#.  In the end it wasn't deemed to be worth the effort, but it's not a senseless concept.

Comment: @Servy you are correct, but my point was to emphasis that it was by the design of the language, I was just using an extreme example, I don't have the specifics on why they designed C# that way

Comment: @johnny5 [Basically just because it wasn't worth the cost to add.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/23/ref-returns-and-ref-locals/)  As is the case for virtually all features that aren't in the language.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is the above `FirstOrDefault` line not valid .NET code?

Because you can only assign a value to a variable, and `FirstOrDefault` doesn't return a variable.

> If the return of FirstOrDefault() isn't a variable, what is it?

It's a value.  You can store the result of `FirstOrDefault` in a variable, bit it isn't itself a variable

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign to the first element of the list, you should just access it at the index: `people[0] = new Person()`.

To answer your other question, it's not a variable; it's an object.  Imagine I tried to write `"foo" = "bar"`.  That would throw an exception -- what does it mean to assign a string literal to another?  Your code is logically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In C# (currently), you cannot set a value to a function call. Instead, you should say:

```
var person = people.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "foo");

if (person != null) {
    person = new Person();
}
```

The C# spec says that the `=` operator:

> stores the value of its right-hand operand in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand operand and returns the value as its result (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx)

A function call is not a storage location, property, or indexer.

This may sound confusing, but think about it this way:

The `=` operator is assignment. `x = y` means that, when you ask for `x`, give me `y` (remember basic algebra?).

You cannot say, "for this function, I want you to always give me `y`" (`FirstOrDefault(x => x.foo) = y`). That kinda goes against a function, which returns a result based on its definition! :)

Comment: I think "currently" is misleading; it's not like this is ever going to be changed.

Comment: I think you are probably right, but it depends on where the "ref returns" spec falls. http://thebillwagner.com/Blog/Item/2016-01-28-C7FeatureProposalRefReturnsandLocals . I could envision that you could ref return and then immediately assign to it... but probably not. I just didn't want my message to get outdated in C#7 :)

Comment: OK, fair enough, although I would be kind of surprised if that one made it in.

Answer (score 1):

`FirstOrDefault()` is a method call and it cannot be used as a variable.

Answer to your question: the value of right hand side is assigned to left hand side, but an object cannot be on the left hand side; only a variable can.

You are trying to assign result of `FirstOrDefault()` method to `People` class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to retrieve person "foo" to do something with it later. You need to store it in a variable. Your code is not valid C# syntax.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var people = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name = "foo" },
            new Person { Name = "bar" }
        };

        var fooPerson = people.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "foo");

        // Use fooPerson
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my point is to understand `why` it is not valid. Why the return of `FirstOrDefault()` cannot be assigned. IE: What rule in .NET states it.

Comment: @mariocatch - you probably want to search on the difference between lvalue and rvalue.

Comment: Because `FirstOrDefault` is a function and you cannot assign it a value.

Answer (score 0):

in the code

```
people.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "foo") = new Person();
```

we see an assignment statement.  Assigning one value to another.   Often with C style languages we call this assigning an lvalue (for left side) an rvalue (or right side.)

```
lvalue = rvalue.
```

There are limits on what the lvalue and rvalue can be.  The rvalue must be able to be evaluated to the same type as the lvalue and the lvalue must be a location in memory (sometimes called a variable.)

If you want to find out more about these issues you can look at language references and how they talk about the lvalue and rvalue in assignment statements.

Comment: The C# specs *don't* use the terms "lvalue" and "rvalue".  It actually uses the terms variables and values, which is what the OP is using.

Comment: @Servy -exactly why I'm using these terms. :)

Comment: So you're going out of your way to use the wrong terms for the context of the question?

Comment: @Servy or I'm going out of my way to provide historical context -- thus using a construct like " Often with C style languages ..."

Comment: Yes, that's *often* the case, but it's not the case *here*, so *here* you're going out of your way to use the incorrect terms, which will prevent the OP from finding the relevant information in the language spec.

Comment: @Servy so I see the link below, which is almost exactly what I wrote -- almost exactly -- I think getting all up in my grill about me saying lvalue not left-hand operand is kind of silly.  This is a Microsoft C# site that says the same thing I wrote.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx

Comment: But that page *doesn't* use the terms lvalue and rvalue.  It uses the terms *value* whenever referring to any value, and explicitly says, "storage location, property, or indexer" instead of lvalue.  It refers to the right hand *operand* and left hand *operand* to refer to the left and right *operands* of the operator, but it doesn't use lvalue and rvalue to describe whether those operands are values or storage locations, it uses the terms "value" and "storage location".  The `+` operator has a right and left hand operand, but they're both values; the right hand operand isn't an rvalue.